# How to block until next data is emitted from hot Flux?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have some function that return some `Flux<Integer>`. This flux is hot, it is being emitting live data. After some time of execution, I want to block until the next Integer is emitted, and assign to a variable. This Integer may not be the first and will not be the last.

I considered `blockFirst()`, but this would block indefinitely as the Flux has already emitted an Integer. I do not care if the Integer is the first or last in the Flux, I just want to block till the next Integer is emitted and assign it to a variable.

How would I do this? I think I could subscribe to the Flux, and after the first value, unsubscribe, but I am hoping there is a better way to do this.

Comment: `myFlux.next().block` ?

Comment: @amanin .next() grabs the first one.

Comment: Why block, just filter them until you're interested again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the replay/buffering behavior of your hot flux. Both `blockFirst()` and `next()` operator do the same things: they wait for the first value **received in the current subscription**.

It is very important to understand that, because in the case of hot fluxes, subscription is independent of source data emission. The first value is not necessarily the first value emitted upstream. It is the first value received by your current subscriber, and that depends on the upstream flow behaviour.
In case of hot fluxes, how they pass values to the subscribers depends both on their buffering and broadcast strategies. For this answer, I will focus only on the buffering aspect:

- If your hot flux does **not** buffer any emitted value (Ex: `Flux.share()`, `Sinks.multicast().directBestEffort()`), then both `blockFirst()` and `next().block()` operators meet your requirement: wait until the next emitted live data in a blocking fashion.
  *NOTE: `next()` has the advantage to allow to become non-blocking if replacing block with cache and subscribe*
- If your upstream flux does buffer some past values, then your subscriber / downsream flow will not only receive live stream. Before it, it will receive (part of) upstream history. In such case, you will have to use a more advanced strategy to skip values until the one you want.
  From your question, I would say that skipping values until an elapsed time has passed can be done using `skipUntilOther(Mono.delay(wantedDuration))`.
  But be careful, because the delay starts from your subscription, not from upstream subscription (to do so, you would require the upstream to provide *timed* elements, and switch to another strategy).
- It is also important to know that Reactor forbids calling `block()` from some Threads (the one used by non-elastic schedulers).

Let's demonstrate all of that with code. In the below program, there's 4 examples:

1. Use *next/blockFirst* directly on a *non-buffering* hot flux
2. Use *skipUntilOther* on a *buffering* hot flux
3. Show that blocking can fail sometimes
4. Try to avoid block operation

All examples are commented for clarity, and launched sequentially in a main function:

```java
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class HotFlux {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("== 1. Hot flux without any buffering");
        noBuffer();

        System.out.println("== 2. Hot flux with buffering");
        withBuffer();

        // REMINDER: block operator is not always accepted by Reactor
        System.out.println("== 3. block called from a wrong context");
        blockFailsOnSomeSchedulers();

        System.out.println("== 4. Next value without blocking");
        avoidBlocking();
    }

    static void noBuffer() {
        // Prepare a hot flux thanks to share().
        var hotFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100))
                          .share();

        // Prepare an operator that fetch the next value from live stream after a delay.
        var nextValue = Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(300))
                        .then(hotFlux.next());

        // Launch live data emission
        var livestream = hotFlux.subscribe(i -> System.out.println("Emitted: "+i));
        try {
            // Trigger value fetching after a delay
            var value = nextValue.block();
            System.out.println("next() -> " + value);
            // Immediately try to block until next value is available
            System.out.println("blockFirst() -> " + hotFlux.blockFirst());
        } finally {
            // stop live data production
            livestream.dispose();
        }
    }

    static void withBuffer() {
        // Prepare a hot flux replaying all values emitted in the past to each subscriber
        var hotFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100))
                .cache();

        // Launch live data emission
        var livestream = hotFlux.subscribe(i -> System.out.println("Emitted: "+i));
        try {
            // Wait half a second, then get next emitted value.
            var value = hotFlux.skipUntilOther(Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(500)))
                               .next()
                               .block();
            System.out.println("skipUntilOther + next: " + value);

            // block first can also be used
            value = hotFlux.skipUntilOther(Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(500)))
                           .blockFirst();
            System.out.println("skipUntilOther + blockFirst: " + value);

        } finally {
            // stop live data production
            livestream.dispose();
        }
    }

    public static void blockFailsOnSomeSchedulers() throws InterruptedException {
        var hotFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100)).share();

        var barrier = new CountDownLatch(1);

        var forbiddenInnerBlock = Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(200))
                // This block will fail, because delay op above is scheduled on parallel scheduler by default.
                .then(Mono.fromCallable(() -> hotFlux.blockFirst()))
                .doFinally(signal -> barrier.countDown());

        forbiddenInnerBlock.subscribe(value -> System.out.println("Block success: "+value),
                                      err   -> System.out.println("BLOCK FAILED: "+err.getMessage()));

        barrier.await();
    }

    static void avoidBlocking() throws InterruptedException {
        var hotFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100)).share();

        var asyncValue = hotFlux.skipUntilOther(Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(500)))
                                .next()
                                // time wil let us verify that the value has been fetched once then cached properly
                                .timed()
                                .cache();

        asyncValue.subscribe(); // launch immediately

        // Barrier is required because we're in a main/test program. If you intend to reuse the mono in a bigger scope, you do not need it.
        CountDownLatch barrier = new CountDownLatch(2);
        // We will see that both subscribe methods return the same timestamped value, because it has been launched previously and cached
        asyncValue.subscribe(value -> System.out.println("Get value (1): "+value), err -> barrier.countDown(), () -> barrier.countDown());
        asyncValue.subscribe(value -> System.out.println("Get value (2): "+value), err -> barrier.countDown(), () -> barrier.countDown());

        barrier.await();
    }
}
```

This program gives the following output:

```
== 1. Hot flux without any buffering
Emitted: 0
Emitted: 1
Emitted: 2
Emitted: 3
next() -> 3
Emitted: 4
blockFirst() -> 4
== 2. Hot flux with buffering
Emitted: 0
Emitted: 1
Emitted: 2
Emitted: 3
Emitted: 4
Emitted: 5
skipUntilOther + next: 5
Emitted: 6
Emitted: 7
Emitted: 8
Emitted: 9
Emitted: 10
Emitted: 11
skipUntilOther + blockFirst: 11
== 3. block called from a wrong context
BLOCK FAILED: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread parallel-6
== 4. Next value without blocking
Get value (1): Timed(4){eventElapsedNanos=500247504, eventElapsedSinceSubscriptionNanos=500247504,  eventTimestampEpochMillis=1674831275873}
Get value (2): Timed(4){eventElapsedNanos=500247504, eventElapsedSinceSubscriptionNanos=500247504,  eventTimestampEpochMillis=1674831275873}
```